# Assign html value to a variable in php

Tags: php, html, global-variables

I ran into an issue that I am not able to figure out. I have a page that I want to add an image of "Verified" or "Unverified". The code I have is the following:

PHP

```
if($listing['priority']==0 {
   $header->set('ver_status,'<img src="images/icon_unverified.png"/>');
} else {
   $header->set('ver_status,'<img src="images/icon_verified.png"/>');
}
```

HTML

```
<?php echo $ver_status; ?>
```

For some reason when I run the page in my website, that variable comes up empty.

The database contains a listing table, and the table contains a priority field which the default value is 0. Unless a customer updates information, which automatically changes to priority field value to 1, all profiles state "unverified"

The $header is the variable assigned to the template

All priority codes at 0 should show the unverified image. All others 1-5 shold show the veriried image.

I did this in a different page and it worked fine. That code was:

```
if (config['language'] == 2) {
   $header->set('language_flag','<img src="images/flags/Spanish.png" />');
} else {
   $header->set('language_flag','<img src="images/flags/English.png" />');
}
```

where code 2 was Spanish and code 1 was English.

Is there something missing in my code that I am not seeing? I am not getting any error messages, just empty values.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing a close paren in your if statement. If that's copied and pasted directly out of your code, that could be causing issues - it should also be causing error messages, but you may have those turned off.

If it's just a typo from copying your code into SO, of course, this is unhelpful.

Comment: that WILL cause issues, not "could" :)

Answer (score 0):

The variable comes up empty because there isn't one. If you want to retrieve an image through echoing a variable's value, simply type

```
if($listing['priority']===0){
    $ver_status='<img src="images/icon_unverified.png">';
}else{
    $ver_status='<img src="images/icon_verified.png">';
}
```

What you're doing in your code is setting an object's key, but when you're trying to get that same key, you're not referencing it correctly. `echo $header->ver_status` is how you should retrieve the value if you don't want to use a normal variable. I suggest reading http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

To note, you have a typo in your code as well. `t('ver_status,'` is an open string.
Also to note, there is no need for a slash in an  tag unless you're using XML.